# A fielder took the catch and made two steps backward and made contact with the boundary rope

Tags: rules, cricket

A fielder took the catch and made two steps backward and made contact with the boundary rope.

Will it be declared as a six or four?

Answer (score 3):

As per [law 19 (Boundaries)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-19-boundaries/)

> (c) A Boundary 6 will be scored if and only if the ball has been
>   struck by the bat and pitches beyond the boundary.  The ball is to be
>   regarded as pitching beyond the boundary even though **before it has
>   pitched**, a fielder
>
> (i) **catches it within the boundary but either has some part of his
>   person touching the boundary or grounded beyond the boundary when he
>   catches the ball or, after catching it, subsequently touches the
>   boundary or grounds some part of his person beyond the boundary while
>   carrying the ball but before completing the catch.**

So it will be considered as a **SIX** because the ball didn't touch the ground at all.

Comment: It's not necessarily a six all the time. So, the above answer is inaccurate on a few counts.

Comment: Could you explain the 'grounds some part of his person beyond the boundary while carrying the ball but before completing the catch' ?

Answer (score 3):

> The act of making the catch, or of fielding the ball, shall start from the time when the ball first comes into contact with some part of a fielder’s person and shall end when a fielder obtains complete control both over the ball and over his own movement.

(19.4.ii)

if he steps out deliberately after having obtained completed control then it's out, if he steps out accidentally as part of the movement of the catch then it's a six.

Comment: This is the answer which is correct: either the fielder has completed the catch by the time he catches the ball (in which case it's out and no runs are scored), or he hasn't, in which case it's a six. There is no way this can be a four, barring the fielder dropping the ball and it e.g. rolling over the boundary. The only other edge case I can see here is the fielder deliberately throwing the ball over the boundary, when it could be *more* than six runs (see Law 19.7).